# Removing unused local variables from .NET code

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

Is there a tool available that can scan a C# or VB.NET project and automatically remove all unused local variables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ahem: FxCop and ReSharper are nice and all, but the compiler will happily ignore unused variables and never even declare them in compiled code if you enable the `optimize` option.

Comment: local variables can be ignored by the compiler, but they might hinder readability of the code by other human developers. depends of course on the code and how complex/ordered/commented it is.

Comment: Where is the optimize option?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReSharper. It will mark all unused variables and allow you to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ReSharper should help you [clean up your code](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9aeaa970-f281-4fb0-aba1-d59d7ed09772) to analyse your code.

Our you van install [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that greys unused local variables out

With both tools you have to delete them your self

Comment: Well, not exactly. ReSharper will not only hightlight the variables; it will also provide you the command to remove them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

FxCop is a useful tool in a number of ways, one of which is that it will point out unused variables and parameters. This is helpful if you have your code going through a continuous integration process.

ReSharper will highlight unused variables and parameters when you are in Visual Studio.

Neither tool will automatically do the removal for you, although it's usually a simple thing to do...R# even provides a shortcut command to remove a single selected variable for you.